# Ошибка после обработки recovery mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, recovery

Запускаю recovery mode, после обработки в самом низу пишется такое:

> mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile/dev/sda1/ windows
>
> mountall: mount /windows [1154] прервано с состоянием 14
>
> mountall: файловая система не может быть подключена: /windows
>
> произошла ошибка при подключении /windows.Нажмите кнопку S чтобы пропустить подключение или M для ручного востановления

Вот это выдает после команды `cat /etc/fstab`:

[image]

И на команды `sudo fdisk -lu и sudo blkid`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, все-таки так:

> mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1/ /windows

Comment: наверное или поможет?

Comment: Ну а вы просто спрашиваете или тоже пытаетесь разобраться. Я же вам не rm -rf / предлагаю.

Comment: Да не правильно у вас целевая директория указана не windows нннада а /windows. Понимаете о чем я?

Comment: каталог /windows существует?

Comment: /windows но на команду mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1/ /windows ничего хорошего не пишется

Comment: А попробуйте так ntfs-3g /dev/sda1/ /windows

Comment: ntfs-3g: failed to access volume '/dev/sda1/': not a directory и так далее ...